# How can i store multiple select box value in database in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have one requirements form in my page..in that form i have users dropdown with select box. I want to select multiple users at a time and need to store selected users in database.

Controller:

```
public function requirement()
{
    $this->load->model('LoginModel');
    $data['user'] = $this->LoginModel->getusers();
    $this->load->view('Admin/requirements',$data);

    $insert = array (
      'role_name'             => $this->input->post('role_name'),
      'vacancies'             => $this->input->post('vacancies'),
      'experience'            => $this->input->post('experience'),
      'jd'                    => $this->input->post('jd'),
      'hiring_contact_name'   => $this->input->post('hiring_contact_name'),
      'hiring_contact_number' => $this->input->post('hiring_contact_number'),
      'user_id'               => $this->input->post('user_id')//this is my foreign key id from users table);
    );
    $this->LoginModel->add_requirement($insert);
}
```

Model:

```
function getusers()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    //echo $this->db->last_query();
    return $query->result();
}
```

View page

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose Vendor</label>
    <select id="chkveg"class="form-control" multiple class="form-control" data-placeholder="user name"  name="user_id[]" >
        <option value="0"></option>
        <?php
        print_r($user);
        foreach ($user as $rows)
        {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $rows->user_id ?>">
                <?php echo ucfirst($rows->first_name) ?>
            </option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: By which way are you submitting the form? By AJAX or PHP?

Comment: i was submitting the form by using php only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make select-box array instead of single value.

```
<select id="chkveg""  class="form-control" multiple class="form-control" data-placeholder="user name"  name="user_id[]" >
```

than you need to ALTER your column datatype to varchar or text.

after that you can implode function to create string value like

```
'user_id'=> implode(',',$this->input->post('user_id')); //eg.1,2,3
```

Reference link : http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should use `'user_id'=>implode(',',$this->input->post('user_id'));` to convert your array into comma separated value. And after that you can store it into database table. Because you can not directly stores the array into database table